# AS3 Advanced Variable Usage - Retrieve Value In Variable Selected Based On Value In Another Variable

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, foreach

I am working on creating a project which allows me to define objects in an XML document and have flash create the required items and display at run time. Needless to say, it is slow progress making this up and learning as I go along.

I have now reached a hurdle, which by comparison should be really easy. But I'm drawing a blank. Despite spending several hours with my good friend Google, I don't seem to be able to phrase this in such as way as to find other people who want to achieve the same.

**Description**

Currently I have a menu handling class, which is where the issue lays. An instance of the menuHandler class is created. It is used by calling a class (LoadFramework) which is passed two strings. One is the address of an XML file, the other is a tag within that XML document to specify what part of it needs to be read.

The XML document is loaded by a class and then parsed into a variable. Then depending on the second string passed (the value of the XML tag), the appropriate part of that XML document is translated onto the screen. This all works fine, but here is the catch...

The only way I have managed to get this working is to use a switch statement with a case for every potential tag. Then I write an appropriate for-each-in loop. The following is an example of one of the case statements (they are all identical except for the "event.dat.XYZ.element" part). "event.dat" is a variable passed by a custom handler, it contains the XML data. XYZ is the name of the tag (in this case "home") and each "element" is a tag containing an attribute.

```
case "home":
    for each (var menuField:XML in event.datPass.home.element) {
        mnDataHold.push(menuFieldHome);
        loopCount ++;
    } // for each (var menuField:XML in event.datPass.home)
    ActionMenu(loopCount);
break;
```

An example of the XML that is held in event.datPass.

```
<home label="home">
    <element label="menuType">HomeScreen</element>
    <element label="screenType">Game.assets.menuScreens.homeScreen</element>
    <element label="buttonCoords">400,50,400,100,400,150,400,200</element>
    <element label="buttonNames">baseButton,baseButton,baseButton,baseButton</element>
    <element label="labelCoords">440,51,425,101,430,151,438,201</element>
    <element label="labelTexts">Play,Options,Credits,More</element>
    <element label="labelColors">0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF</element>
    <element label="labelSizes">22,22,22,22</element>
    <element label="labelBolds">true,true,true,true</element>
    <element label="buttonCommands">startGame,diplaysMnuOptions,displayMnuCredits,displayMnuMoreGames</element>
</home>
```

**The Request**
What I want to do is replace part or all of the object in the for-each-in loop with a variable, and then evaluate the string as a reference rather than using it as the value.

So that I can end up ditching the switch and simply have something like:

```
for each (var menuField:XML in [mnVariable]) {
```

mnVariable would contain the string, eg "event.datPass.home.element".
Or:

```
for each (var menuField:XML in event.dat.[mnVariable].element) {
```

mnVariable would contain the string, eg "home".

However, written the first way, all that happens is that the for-each-in loop looks in mnVariable to find the value in menuField, which it won't find. Written the second way it will just throw an error. I need [mnVariable] to be used to evaluate as meaning 'look in the object named by this string'

Any pointers are very gladly received.

Comment: Could you give the error that appears when you try the second method? It might give a clue as to what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: puggsoy - The error that was thrown by the code I was referring to was "1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before leftbracket."

It was due to the period placed before the [mnVariable]. Had I had the sense (or perhaps more sleep) to have tried without that leading period, the code would have worked - as highlighted by JimmiTh's post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally not a fan of having data-defining element names in XML, but - assuming `event.dat` is actually an [`XML` object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html), and not an arbitrary object that you've manually parsed the XML into (can't tell from the question) - this is really a question about ECMAScript for XML (E4X) rather than variables in general.

If so, this should work:

```
for each (var menuField:XML in event.dat.child(mnVariable).element)
{
   // Do something
}
```

Can't test at the moment, but this may also work (it's part of E4X standard, but not sure if Adobe implemented it):

```
// Note, no dot before the indexer:
for each (var menuField:XML in event.dat[mnVariable].element)
{
   // Do something
}
```

The latter is also generally the way to access a property of an object using a string property name, so if `event.dat` *is* an arbitrary object of manually parsed XML - as opposed to an actual `XML` object - the second example should also work.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, and you were spot on.

Both variants work, which kind of has me kicking myself (I tried what I figured was going to be the right method (the second of the two you listed), but has an extra period (between the datPass and the [mnVariable]) - thus creating my error).

Anyway, Thanks again. Now I have more reading to do with regard ECMA Script.

Comment: I added a link to Adobe's XML documentation, which also has "Related links" to most of their E4X documentation (which is sparse to say the least). If you want to read more, have a look at [senocular's introduction](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/as3withflashcs3/?page=4), which actually covers much more of it.

Comment: I think it might be XMLLists but I caution using for each with xml related stuff, every now and again it personally causes frustration.